# Swift: CALayer bounds contains NaN: [nan nan; nan nan]?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, calayer

I have no idea what is going on here despite looking at similar answers. I have made a custom UIImageview that is supposed to start animating as soon as it is created:

```
class HeaderAnimator: UIImageView {

    var travelUp = Bool(false)

    var img = UIImage()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        //init

        //ALWAYS SAME COLOR - black with less opacity, just change shapes randomly via parent
        self.image = img

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1,
                       delay: 0.2,
                       options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseIn,
                       animations: { () -> Void in
                        //animate
                        if(self.travelUp)
                        {
                             self.center.y += screenSize.height * (50/screenSize.height)
                        }
                        else {
                            self.center.y -= screenSize.height * (50/screenSize.height)
                        }

        }, completion: { (finished) -> Void in
            // ....
            print("done")
            self.removeFromSuperview()
        })
```

Then Im trying to spawn these views on a timer in another view:

```
let rand = Double(arc4random_uniform(4))
       var bgTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 3, target: self, selector: #selector(self.animateInBg), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

func animateInBg()
    {
        var randPos = CGPoint()
        var upOrDown = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(2)))
        //print(upOrDown)

        let h = HeaderAnimator(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.bounds.width * (40/self.bounds.width), height: self.bounds.width * (40/self.bounds.width)))
        h.img = UIImage(named: "rocket")!

        switch upOrDown {
        case 0: //down
            randPos = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(arc4random()).truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: ( self.bounds.width)), y: self.bounds.height * 0.9)
            h.travelUp = false
            //h.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: -1)

        case 1: //up
            randPos = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(arc4random()).truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: ( self.bounds.width)), y: self.bounds.height * 0)
            h.travelUp = true
        default:
            randPos = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(arc4random()).truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: ( self.bounds.width)), y: self.bounds.height * 0)
            h.travelUp = true
        }

        h.center = CGPoint(x: self.bounds.width * 0.5, y: 0)
        self.addSubview(h)
    }
```

These views are supposed to show up then move either up or down out of the view then delete. Shortly after one spawns however, I get error: `CALayerInvalidGeometry CALayer bounds contains NaN: [nan nan; nan nan]`

What does this mean? What am I doing wrong just creating these views?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Per Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimageview), you should not subclass `UIImageView`. Instead, they recommend that you subclass `UIView` and do your drawing there.

> Do not use image views for custom drawing. TheUIImageView class does
>   not draw its content using the draw(_:) method. Use image views only
>   to present images. To do custom drawing involving images, subclass
>   UIView directly and draw your image there.

Comment: Why is this? Thank you for your answer.